# Truffle 3.0 upgrade changes, migration and javascript errors

Tags: dapp-development, truffle

Hey I'm trying to upgrade to Truffle 3 and it's a complete mess. The migrations wont work as there are two errors:

```
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Migrations error: contract binary not set. Can't deploy new instance.
```

Also after following the sample javascript file I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Comment: Please add your migration scripts to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one function that is an abstract function in your contract.

`function addr(string _name) constant returns (address o_owner)`

The whole contract is compiled as an abstract contract, so you will get this error message.
It might be like me, that you never ment to write an abstract contract, but a but fast copy pasting of some code, and simsallabim, you have some abstract functions without thinking about it.
So either add functions bodies to them or remove them.

Then your contract will compile.